# Windows code signing certificate - what is the reader and cryptographic card for?

Tags: windows, windows-10, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I was looking at this code signing certificate on Certum:

https://en.sklep.certum.pl/data-safety/code-signing-certificates/open-source-code-signing-930.html

It has two options, either with "reader and cryptographic card" (86 EUR) or without (28 EUR).

I've contacted Certum about it and they say:

> From this year Microsoft requires to install code signing certificate on cryptographic card and reader is used to read this card

However I cannot find any information about this on the internet or official Microsoft website (It's possible I'm not searching for the right keywords since the Certum page is translated from Polish).

Is it true that this card and device are absolutely necessary to sign the software? Any idea where I can find information about all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have telephone called Certum and they said it's necessary. You can however go with more expensive option of Open Source Code Signing in Cloud, and they claim you don't need the card and reader then... This is what I'm going for, but I was just as surprised as you that I need some hardware...

Answer (score 2):

This might be a late reply, but here's some info in case anybody comes across this post.

[CA Security Council](https://casecurity.org/2016/12/08/leading-certificate-authorities-and-microsoft-introduce-new-standards-to-protect-consumers-online/):

> Stronger protection for private keys: The best practice will be to use
>   a FIPS 140-2 Level 2 HSM or equivalent. Studies show that code signing
>   attacks are split evenly between issuing to bad publishers and issuing
>   to good publishers that unknowingly allow their keys to be
>   compromised. That enables an attacker to sign malware stating it was
>   published by a legitimate company. Therefore, companies must either
>   store keys in hardware they keep on premise hardware, or in a new
>   secure cloud-based code signing cloud-based service.

[GlobalSign](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/2705869-minimum-requirements-for-code-signing):

> Microsoft has announced that they will be adopting the new Minimum
>   Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Code Signing
>   Certificates issued by the Certificate Authority Security Council
>   (CASC). This means, beginning February 1, 2017, Certificate
>   Authorities (CAs) will need to meet these requirements in order for
>   their certificates to be trusted in Windows platforms.  As such,
>   GlobalSign will be making the changes listed below starting January
>   30, 2017.
>
> All Code Signing Certificates Will Be Issued with USB tokens

Comment: Does this mean that all new signing keys must be distributed on HSMs? I am finding surprisingly little information about this online.